# Apache shutdown unexpectedly, No ports are using but still not working

Tags: apache, server, xampp, localhost

i am using Xampp from "https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html" for php version 7.1.7

I have change my ports:8080(httpd.conf)  and 4433 (httpd-ss;.conf) also tried some other port but while starting Apache I found this issue every time

```
2:48:41 AM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
2:48:41 AM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
2:48:41 AM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
2:48:41 AM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
2:48:41 AM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
2:48:41 AM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
2:48:41 AM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

and Apache (error.log)

```
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:02.474102 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4832:tid 600] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:02.881341 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 4832:tid 600] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:02.998856 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4832:tid 600] AH00455: Apache/2.4.26 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2l PHP/7.0.21 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:02.998856 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4832:tid 600] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Jun 15 2017 12:39:41
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:02.998856 2017] [core:notice] [pid 4832:tid 600] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:03.013855 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4832:tid 600] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1088
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:04.169927 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1088:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:04.693597 2017] [ssl:warn] [pid 1088:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Wed Jul 19 02:45:04.746592 2017] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1088:tid 624] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

and this is Service setting

[image: Service setting]

Error appear error Dialogue

[image: Error Dialogue]

I am using window 10, can someone give the solve.

Comment: You are trying to use an SSL certificate that does not match or contain a subject alternative name related to the website / host. This will cause Apache to fail hence the error you see in the error log. If you want Apache to run disable the SSL setting or fix your self-signed certificate.